# override ActionLink Behavior , and parameters to process link appearance according to user privileges (asp.net mvc3)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, actionlink

I want to process user privileges (edit , read,new) in my website , I am thinking about passing additional parameter byte `MyRoles`  which has user privileges code i.e.: 0-read only , 1 - full control , 2-edit and read

So how I can override `Html.ActionLink` razor method to work with that , and is my method the best way to process this issue (User privileges) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> and is my method the best way to process this issue (User privileges) ?

No, passing roles as parameters to your actions would represent a security flaw as the user could pass any role he likes.

The correct way to do this is to use the Role provider. You associate roles to your users and then define in which role the user need to be in order to access a particular action.

For example:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Readers")]
public ActionResult SomeAction() 
{
    // only users belonging to the readers role will be able to access this action
}
```

Once you have properly secured the server side you could conditionally show/hide anchors and stuff in your Razor views:

```
@if (User.IsInRole("Readers"))
{
    @Html.ActionLink("read the news", "SomeAction")
}
```

And to avoid writing those ifs you could write a custom HTML helper:

```
@Html.RoleActionLink("read the news", "Some Action", "Readers")
```

The default Membership and Role providers use the default aspnetdb but you could of course extend or write custom ones in order to query your own data.

Comment: well , that`s good point ,  what if user has many custom roles , I mean "FullControler" in some controller , but "reader" in another controller ,according to your suggestion , in corporate web site the user may have 10s or 100s of roles

Comment: In this case you define the `FullController` and `Reader` roles and make the user belong to both those roles. Then you simply decorate the controller/action with the `[Authorize]` attribute as I have shown in my answer and specify the required role in order to execute this action. You could also specify multiple roles by separating them with comma.

Comment: the authorization happens when user access the controller , the ideas is not showing "Edit" link if the user was just reader , your method is effective and secured ,but to be completed I have to show the only authorized links to user , what you suggest?

Comment: That's what I have covered in the second part of my answer. You could either test if the user belongs to a given role (using `if User.IsInRole("SomeRole")`) and conditionally display the link or write a custom helper that does this check before rendering the link.

Comment: ok thanks , Sorry didn`t notice the second part, I think this will make it .